# I have two tables and the id from table1 is two columns in table2. How can I display this correctly?

Tags: sql

I have a teams table called `list`, and a games table called `games`.

A `Team_ID` could be in either the `games_home` or the `games_away` column. How do I get this to work in SQL?

```
SELECT list.*, games.*
FROM list 
INNER JOIN games ON (list.Team_ID = games.games_away) 
                 AND (list.Team_ID = games.games_home);
```

This does not show any results.

Image of relationship:

[image]

[example of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMNbP.png)

id 13 = man u
id 9 = liverpool
etc

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdPWg.png)

Comment: You'll won't be able to get those grouped column in a SQL listing but my answer is doing what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data for both teams in a single row you'll need two joins:

```
SELECT g.*, l1.Team as home_team, l2.Team as away_team, l1.*, l2.*
FROM games g
    INNER JOIN list l1 ON l1.Team_ID = g.games_home
    INNER JOIN list l2 ON l2.Team_ID = g.games_away
```

Select only the columns you actually need to return and alias them as I did above so you can distinguish home vs. away.

Comment: it's just coming up with undefined index: l2.team

Comment: @Dan That column name appears in your diagram. Either way you should be able to adapt the column listing according to your needs by following that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a UNION ALL with two queries: one selects home matches, the other selects away matches

```
SELECT l.*, g.*
  FROM list l
 INNER JOIN games g
    ON g.games_away = l.team_ID
 UNION ALL
SELECT l.*, g.*
  FROM list l
 INNER JOIN games g
    ON g.games_home = l.team_ID
```